# How to compare rows in ag-grid

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to compare two similar rows in my ag-grid and highlight the difference between them. Most column entries are the same but I'd like for a cell to be highlighted if it's different from its predecessor.

Is there any way I can do that in ag-grid? Or will I have to use an HTML table and loop through every entry?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I have the same question and can't find a solution anywhere. Did you find a way to compare rows in ag-grid or is looping the only way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a grid option as a function, named `getRowStyle`, as follows:

**in HTML:**

```
<ag-grid-angular
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
....></ag-grid-angular>
```

**in .ts:**

```
import { 
  GridOptions,
} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
```

and inside of class:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions;
```

in the constructor:

```
constructor(){
    this.gridOptions = {
        getRowStyle: (params: any) => {
            if (params.data){
                    if(params.data.display.id === 15) {
                        return { background: '#eee', 'font-weight': 750 };
                    }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

This is applying **style** what you return as a response of **getRowStyle** function

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the difference highlighting with the following defaultColDef function:

```
  defaultColDef = {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        const rowIndex = params.node.rowIndex;
        const columnId = params.colDef.field;
           
        const previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
        if(params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(previousRowIndex) === undefined){
          return { 'background-color': null};
        }

        const currentValue = params.value;
        const previousValue = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(previousRowIndex).data[columnId];
       
        if (currentValue !== previousValue) {
          return { 'background-color': 'lightblue' };
        }
  
        return { 'background-color': null};
      }
  }
```

This assumes you are scanning from top-to-bottom of the grid and highlighting the cells as you go down the rows in the grid. If you want to go from bottom-to-top and highlight as you travel up the grid then you just need to change *previousRowIndex* to:

```
const previousRowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
```

Here is the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-diff-highlighting